# How to debug a nodejs readline app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to debug a simple nodejs readline programme.

```
var readline = require("readline");
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What's your name \n",function(answer){
    var x =10;  // set the break point here
    console.log("your name is ",answer);
    rl.close();
});
```

I set the break point at var x = 10; inside callback function of rl.question().but the break point never hits.

Why this happening I am confused.
Then how to debug a readline programme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using node-inspector? I was able to debug fine from there. If your program is terminal-based, using a web-based debugger and thus leaving the terminal available for the app might avoid some confusion and trickiness.

[image: screen grab of node-inspector]

Answer (score 1):

I use

node --inspect yourFile.js

which outputs: 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/abcXXX-....

I access it through Vivaldi, Chrome or Opera using:
vivaldi://inspect    or
chrome://inspect

On this page it shows 'Remote Targets' and you click inspect on yourFile. 
That opens basically the same debugger you use in the web console.